# postgresql, hide database from listing

Tags: postgresql

I'm have a problem.
On my server i have many users.
I want to each user can see only database to what have access.

This is possible?
How to solve this problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917484/allow-postgres-user-to-only-list-his-own-database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917484/allow-postgres-user-to-only-list-his-own-database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

solution requires changes in postgresql catalogs

Comment: Please be more specific. How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible on the database layer (i.e. on `psql`), AFAIK. pgAdmin added a custom functionality to hide inaccessible databases, but this is nothing more than a custom `SELECT .. WHERE` query to keep the list of databases short.